# Active Directory and FileVault

Tags: macos, filevault, active-directory

Is there a way to set up users on Mountain Lion to be available in the FileVault boot screen if the users are Active Directory users managed through *Quest Authentication Services* (QAS)?

I would like to have the following working:

- User is managed through AD using QAS
- FileVault encryption is used for the whole disk, not just the user's home directory
- The AD user is used in the FileVault boot screen

Is this possible or does anyone use a similar configuration?

**Update**

Since I haven't received an answer here, and haven't found a way to use both QAS and FileVault, I have removed QAS (now using a local user account again), and then enabled FileVault 2 for the disk encryption. Logging in with the local user works fine.

The downside is that I have to authenticate separately to some network drives now that previously didn't require authentication due to the AD integration, but that's a small price.

Comment: If you're managing multiple AD users on FV-enabled Macs, you might want to take a look at [Cauliflower Vest](https://code.google.com/p/cauliflowervest/) for distributed key escrow and recovery.

Answer (score 1):

In our work environment, I have our Macs bind directly to Active Directory with no service (like QAS) in the middle. The AD user has a local home folder, we do not use Network Homes. We use FileVault 2 with no issues. The AD user's name shows up on the FileVault screen and they are able to unencrypt their laptop with their normal network credentials. So yes, it should work fine unless QAS is adding something bizarre into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that QAS uses network accounts and not mobile accounts, as it handles credential caching itself and doesn't need a record for each AD user in the local directory.  The reason this is a problem for people wanting to use FileVault is that you have to select the users who can unlock the drive via the Mac's GUI, and network accounts won't show up.  The solution is to log in as an AD user and then convert the account to mobile in the Users & Groups preference pane.  QAS will continue to facilitate authentication with AD and the local directory will make the account available for use with things like FileVault.